# regex not matching with some numbers

Tags: java, regex, vaadin

I have this regex: `^(\d*.?\d*)$` for all numbers, but some numbers won't match with this regex

Some Examples:

```
54139 // work
24.711 // won't work, not a float but dot is the separator
0 // won't work
60 // won't work
```

I used this regex in RegexValidator. I'm validating a textfield:

```
TextField textField = new TextField(caption);
textField.setValue(value);
textField.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator(value + " ...",10, 50, true));
textField.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("^(\\d*.?\\d*)$", value + " ..."));
```

I tried it with another regex: `^[0-9,.]+$`

Comment: Escape the dot... `\.` with a slash!

Comment: What do you mean `not a float but dot is the separator` ? Should it be parsed as two separate integers?

Comment: @Aaron, the number is not decimal number. dot is the separator

Comment: And what should happen then? Do you wish to accept this value, part of this value, or reject it all along? Because in my mind since there's a separator, it's not just a number, and should be rejected.

Comment: i want to accept all number: 30; 90; 20.156; 0; 152,125

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl won't work with \.

Comment: Then use `[\.,]?` to check for a separator. Don't make it too ambiguous. Simply putting `.?` is confusing.

Comment: @k-five [it's already optional](https://regex101.com/r/Dwx3tP/2), the `*` quantifier accepts 0 to n occurrences

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl no need to escape the dot in a character class, it loses its meaning as a meta-character in this context

Comment: `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` with `m`-flag or `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`

Comment: Are you using your TextField in multiline mode? I think that might be the problem, since your current regex should work well on a single-line input.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you're validating the content of a multi-line `TextField` and want to accept a content consisting of one or multiple lines of non-empty sequences of `.`-separated floats and integers.

This statement can be simplified as follows : you're looking to match a sequence of numbers separated by `.` or linefeeds, where a number can contain a decimal part.

If would then use the following `RegexpValidator` :

```
new RegexpValidator("\\d+(,\\d+)?([.\\n]\\d+(,\\d+)?)*", true, value + "...")
```

In this regular expression, a number is represented as `\\d+(,\\d+)?`, which represents a mandatory integer part followed by an optional decimal part with its comma separator.

The global regular expression accepts a number such as defined above, followed by a (possibly empty) sequence of other numbers preceded by one of the accepted delimiters, a `.` or a linefeed.

I verified my answer with the following expression which returns `true` :

```
"54139\n12.5\n1,2.5,3\n12,5".matches("\\d+(,\\d+)?([.\\n]\\d+(,\\d+)?)*");
```

Note that I removed the anchors you used and used the `complete` parameter of `RegexpValidator` instead.

The regex could arguably be reduced to `\d+([.,\n]\d+)*`, but would then stop representing the difference between `.` which is a separator between numbers and `,` which is part of the numbers. It doesn't matter at the runtime for a validator, but could bring confusion to people maintaining your code, and couldn't easily be reused if you later want to match the different numbers.